# Jersey Rx client jersey-client-async-executor shutdown

Tags: spring-boot, jersey, rx-java, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [jersey-client-async-executor-0] but has failed to stop it.

How to gracefully shutdown the jersey-client-async-executor?

This is used with Spring Boot, `JerseyRxClient` with embedded tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Jersey Gracefully terminates the thread once the request is complete. 
I am using spring boot scheduler to make asynchronous request using rx jersey client.

I had the same doubt as everytime a scheduler runs, jersey client creates new threads incrementing the number. 
To be sure that the thread is terminated,

Simple Test:

```
In your subscriber, 
    Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
```

this will not list the jersey-client-async-executor-* which was used to make the request.